# SQLITE - Sorting

Tags: sqlite, sorting, group-by

I have this DB schema with 2 tables one for Athletes and one for Results.

I'm trying to get the last time elapse (or greater) of each athletes using this query:

> ### Select Query

```
Select Athletes.BibNumber, Athletes.ChipNumber, Athletes.FirstName, Athletes.LastName, Athletes.Sex, Athletes.Category, count(Results.ElapsedTime) as         Lapcount, Results.ElapsedTime
From Results, Athletes
Where Results.ChipNumber = Athletes.ChipNumber and Athletes.Category = 'A (Elite)' and Athletes.Sex = 'M' and Results.Active = 1
Group by Athletes.ChipNumber
Order by (Athletes.Sex = 'M') DESC, Athletes.Sex, Athletes.Category, Lapcount DESC, Results.ElapsedTime ASC;
```

This works ok if the times are added incrementally, but if I edit the time and add or change a time and the record ID is larger then the time the sort order is not applied.

Running the above query the result is:

```
    "1" "2018001"   "User"  "2" "M" "A (Elite)" "5" "00:00:00.000"
    "2" "2018002"   "User"  "1" "M" "A (Elite)" "5" "01:18:09.923"
```

But I would like to have:

```
    "1" "2018001"   "User"  "2" "M" "A (Elite)" "5" "01:11:51.384"
    "2" "2018002"   "User"  "1" "M" "A (Elite)" "5" "01:18:09.923"
```

> ### DB Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Results` (
`ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`ChipNumber`    TEXT,
`ReaderTime`    TEXT,
`Antenna`   TEXT,
`ElapsedTime`   TEXT,
`Active`    INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO `Results` (ID,ChipNumber,ReaderTime,Antenna,ElapsedTime,Active) VALUES
(72354,'2018002','2018/07/29 12:01:39.000','Gun','00:00:00.000',1),
(72383,'2018001','2018/07/29 12:19:07.975','S3','00:17:28.974',1),
(72386,'2018002','2018/07/29 12:19:51.877','S3','00:18:12.876',1),
(72411,'2018001','2018/07/29 12:36:49.677','S3','00:35:10.676',1),
(72415,'2018002','2018/07/29 12:39:29.232','S3','00:37:50.231',1),
(72433,'2018001','2018/07/29 12:55:08.811','S3','00:53:29.810',1),
(72439,'2018002','2018/07/29 12:59:37.760','M3','00:57:58.759',1),
(72452,'2018001','2018/07/29 13:13:30.385','S3','01:11:51.384',1),
(72456,'2018002','2018/07/29 13:19:48.923','Manual','01:18:09.923',1),
(72465,'2018001','2018/07/29 12:01:39.000','Gun','00:00:00.000',1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Athletes` (
`ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`FirstName` TEXT,
`LastName`  TEXT,
`Sex`   TEXT DEFAULT 'M',
`Category`  TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
`BibNumber` INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
`ChipNumber`    TEXT DEFAULT 0,
`Active`    BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO `Athletes` (ID,FirstName,LastName,Sex,Category,BibNumber,ChipNumber,Active) VALUES
(3,'User','1','M','A (Elite)',2,'2018002',1),
(29,'User','2','M','A (Elite)',1,'2018001',1);
```

Comment: You are aggregating on the chipnumber, but not specifying what values to pull for the other fields. I'm supprised this is valid.  Couldn't you just use a "max(ElapsedTime) as ElapsedTime. Although, it would be a text based sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is due to the following (see highlighted) :-

> If the SELECT statement is an aggregate query without a GROUP BY
>   clause, then each aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated
>   once across the entire dataset. **Each non-aggregate expression in the
>   result-set is evaluated once for an arbitrarily selected row of the
>   dataset**. The same arbitrarily selected row is used for each
>   non-aggregate expression. Or, if the dataset contains zero rows, then
>   each non-aggregate expression is evaluated against a row consisting
>   entirely of NULL values.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - SELECT - 3. Generation of the set of result rows.](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

As such to ensure that you get the maximum value for the elapsed time you should use an aggregate function, thus **`max`** in your case.

Therefore, I believe the following will work for you :-

```
SELECT Athletes.BibNumber, Athletes.ChipNumber, Athletes.FirstName, Athletes.LastName, Athletes.Sex, Athletes.Category, 
    count(Results.ElapsedTime) AS Lapcount, 
    max(Results.ElapsedTime) AS ElapsedTime
FROM Results JOIN Athletes ON Results.ChipNumber = Athletes.ChipNumber
GROUP BY Athletes.ChipNumber
ORDER BY (Athletes.Sex = 'M') DESC, Athletes.Sex, Athletes.Category, Lapcount DESC, Results.ElapsedTime ASC;
```